# WiFi point-to-point in coastal environment - 2.4 vs 5 GHz

Tags: rf, antenna, wireless, wifi, networking

I am planning to provide Internet to a sea floating platform through point-to-point antennas from the coast.

The distance is approximately 300 meters and the platform is quite shaky due to the weather. The location is quite remote, so there is near-zero interference from nearby networks.

I am divided between using 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz WiFi antennas and trying to think of possible differences in signal quality.

2.4 GHz equipment is cheaper than 5 GHz, but relative added cost isn't much of a problem. QoS is the main target, as there will be video streaming via the link.

- I've read that 5 GHz provides better speed but needs to be accurately pointed, which is difficult due to the weather. Will a misalignment in antenna line of sight be more "severe" with 5 GHz than 2.4 GHz?
- I am guessing that 2.4 GHz is more "robust" in moisture, fog, etc. than 5 GHz, due to longer wavelength. Does that make sense or is the difference negligible?

Comment: Either of these will need line of sight to work at 300m. And ideally directed antennas.

Comment: Will a large ship ever pass between the coast and the platform?  That would likely obstruct the signal.  5GHz is more "directional."  Maybe put an infrared emitter on the platform antenna, and have the coast antenna (very slowly) align to that.

Comment: A glance at the TP Link datasheet says its parabolic external wifi units have a beam with of 9 degrees horizontally, they claim up to 30 km for point-to-point links under optimal conditions.  Perhaps it's less critical than you'd imagine.

Comment: why not use both in case one faces a problem that hamper it?

Comment: @Lundin Yes, fortunately Line Of Sigh is almost guaranteed on site

Comment: @rdtsc Fortunately Line Of Sigh is almost guaranteed on site

Comment: @dandavis Well, the site is quite far from my location and I am trying to reduce time needed on-site for setup. The distance between antennas isn't that far, thus each antenna solution ( 2.4 or 5 ) would certainly work and connect. I was trying to optimize my link, as it will serve for video streaming purposes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as your bandwidth requirement doesn't exceed about 100 Mbps, 2.4 GHz is a better choice for reaching long ranges. You may want to distribute the wi-fi on the floating platform with a 5 GHz access point, reducing interference with the 2.4 GHz link.

Look for business or commercial grade wi-fi links, with weatherproof housings for the antenna and transceiver. You could use a directional antenna on the shore installation, but avoid it on the floating platform as the pitching and rolling could misdirect the beam.

You need line-of-sight -- no trees or buildings in the path -- and the antennas should both be mounted outside the structures. Roof-level height will be adequate to reach 300 m over a sea surface.

Comment: He could probably still use a patch type directional antenna, as long as the craft isn't rotating around.